# Examples of Multiplicative Noise

Tags: stochastic-calculus, signal-processing, noise

I understand the [main idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_noise) behind a multiplicative noise in signal processing, but I'm struggling to see it expressed in a specific example. Could someone help me?

For example, if I have a system of ODEs to which I intend to implement a multiplicative Gaussian noise, do I simply add a noise term to each equation?

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer this question, you would in general need to understand how the noise enters your system. The thing is, you do not add multiplicative noise to a system, but there is noise working on your system that results in a multiplicative term. 
Think for example of the following equation:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=x(1-x)(x-a),
\end{align*}
where $a$ is some external parameter. If we now suppose that the parameter $a$ fluctuates around a fixed value $\bar a$, i.e. we assume $a=\bar a+\beta_t$, the ODE above would be replaced by the SDE
\begin{align*}
dx=x(1-x)(x-\bar a)dt+u(1-u)d\beta_t.
\end{align*}
As you can see, we added Gaussian noise to a parameter, but the effect on the variable you are interested in, $x(t)$, is multiplicative.